# WARN Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8004 (reason: ?)

Tags: xampp

1 .. i am using laravel 10 nd using xampp server while running command php artisan serve i am getting

WARN  Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8004 (reason: ?). my sql running fine i am also able to view my database but problem in apache server    . downloaded latest xampp ;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.